# Using Transduction to reverse Antibiotic Resistance?

Tags: bacteriology, medicine, biomedical-technology

Is it possible to use reverse transduction to reverse antibiotic resistance. Since antibitiotic resistance is causee by transduction of the F factor, is it possible to induce a F+ non antibiotic resistant bacteria into a region of F- resistant bacteria?

Comment: This seems very confused. Apart from anything else, The F plasmid doesn't encode an antibiotic resistance. Are you asking if it is possible to get rid of a plasmid from a bacterial strain?

Comment: @AlanBoyd Wait is it the R plasmid? Hmm I guess so... My question is whter we can make resistant bacteria transfer genes with non resistant bacteria.

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/64618/6307

Comment: OK bacteria with an F plasmid can transfer their other plasmids (which may encode antibiotic resistance) during F-mediated conjugation. Now, starting from there, what is the question?

Comment: @AlanBoyd i think canadianer's link has already answered my question . Thanks anyway!