# Induce plasmid acquisition in bacteria to make them susceptible to antibiotics

Tags: microbiology, plasmids

Is it possible to use plasmids as a way of creating antibiotic susceptibility in bacteria.

For example; in Microbiology, an introduction 13th edition by Pearson , Page 230 "the researchers traced the drug-resistance plasmid to a plasmid found in *E.coli* that resided in the volunteers before the study".

I was wondering if it is possible to induce plasmids that make those bacteria susceptible.

They have to be in a first instance good for the bacteria, for example an enzyme that allows the bacteria to use a compound. But  through an antibiotic it would make that enzyme catalyze useful compounds of the bacteria, working the antibiotic as a cofactor of such enzyme.
Is it possible?
I was thinking on it as a "trojan plasmid".

Thanks.

**Edit:** Linking to this question: [Could plasmids and conjugation mechanisms be used against antibiotic-resistant bacteria?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/64602/53354) , it talks about those "trojan horse" plasmids referring them in a way that seems to be linked to a bactericidal function, if instead the  plasmids are linked to a good survival rate in one situation (example, 36°C) but to a bacteriostatic situation ( temperature goes up to 39°) or such a way like hemoglobin works with CO, it's fundamental for us but selection hasn't worked to get through this problem and still binds to the molecule.

This type of coevolution in *Wolbachia* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia makes the host insect susceptible to needing the bacteria for reproduction despite being good in some environmental conditions it induces infertility in others.

Or inducing variants of genes that are still with functionality but trunked under certain conditions, if those conditions aren't present in the environment, the gene variant could spread without causing problems competing with the original variant until those environmental conditions are met reaching an equilibrium in which a % of the population could be used as a target of that antibiotic.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/64602/6307) and its answers.

Comment: @canadianer Thanks! It has solved some of my questions, but I still feel I am in a slightly different situation, focusing more in the plasmid genetic equilibrium than in the complete widespread throughout the population.